# How do I assign the same Conditional Rendering Rules to Multiple Components?

Tags: presentation, rules-engine

How could a Content Author copy a Conditional Rendering Rule from one component, to many others?

I think the best solution would be to set the Conditional Rendering Rule on the Data Template of the component.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to copy the rules from page to page. This is because the rules are in the xml for the presentation details. And it is really tough to read.

```
    <rls>
        <ruleset>
           <rule uid="{A7CBE2DB-B320-49CE-B16C-6BFE6DAF8A9F}" s:name="Member - ALTS">
              <conditions>
                 <and uid="0DADC70F0B1546DD9E1E72F6645F392A">
                    <condition uid="B9075F167B6D4908B9BE2D18A16B6295" s:id="{C57E0BD7-8E96-410B-BB67-C2F66C9BF129}" />
                    <condition uid="65B8A95CE14E43449D10B539C47799E1" s:id="{6426B5B4-83E9-4E24-BA97-43293A10B47D}" s:ProfileName="Interests" s:PatternName="ALTS" />
                 </and>
              </conditions>
              <actions>
                 <action uid="F02729C93C774ABA9D3956A087138F74" s:id="{0F3C6BEC-E56B-4875-93D7-2846A75881D2}" s:DataSource="{C4D04549-96D1-43DC-A6B7-522F520244A3}" />
              </actions>
           </rule>
           <rule uid="{F60982A2-A425-4BAA-A17C-8B0CAB4C3090}" s:name="Member - Triathlete">
              <conditions>
                 <and uid="375C1ECD7B21412995612814828E29C4">
                    <condition uid="FDB51B22CAAC4799B67903C166C9988B" s:id="{C57E0BD7-8E96-410B-BB67-C2F66C9BF129}" />
                    <condition uid="7A1B1FEBF57D4C92859AC90428DFD56B" s:id="{6426B5B4-83E9-4E24-BA97-43293A10B47D}" s:ProfileName="Interests" s:PatternName="Triathlete" />
                 </and>
              </conditions>
              <actions>
                 <action uid="10E1FD2F532E4D1A86EF2753772A90F9" s:id="{0F3C6BEC-E56B-4875-93D7-2846A75881D2}" s:DataSource="{3A41636A-4D94-4913-B617-69B8842FE47A}" />
              </actions>
           </rule>
        </ruleset>
     </rls>
```

The thing you can do is predefine your rules and then they only have to select a single rule and not build the rule set again. You can find predefined rules under the item `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Personalization/Predefined Rules`

Answer (score 1):

If the content items with the desired presentation are all based on the same template, you can add your presentation and personalisation to the template _StandardValues item. All pages based on that template will then inherit the presentation.